# Creating an iOS/OS X cross-platform class

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I read a lot of questions about creating a cross-platform library for these 2 systems. Every answer points to static library as the solution.

I don't want to end up with a static library, I'd like to create a class with methods for iOS and their counterpart for OS X.

```
-(void)createColor:(NSColor*);
-(void)createColor:(UIColor*);
```

The first problem that I have is that I can't find a way to use classes that are available only in a specific system. So for example, how could I manage a function that works with `UIColor` in iOS and with `NSColor` in OS X?

If I create a project for iOS, when I look into `Foundation.h` I can't find `NSColor.h` in the headers list.

I thought to use the `TARGET_OS_MAC` and `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` definitions to make a distinction between the two systems... I'm on the right way?

**EDIT to add more info:**

At the moment I have 2 targets: an iOSTestApp and OSxTestApp. For these targets I have included the needed frameworks depending on the system.

Using `TARGET_OS_MAC` and `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` works only when I select the OSXTestApp as active target. When I select the iOSAppTest, Xcode returns errors for OS X data type (i.e. `NSColor`)

Here an example of the code that produces these errors:

```
#if TARGET_OS_MAC
-(void)createColor:(NSColor*)color;    

#elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE
-(void)createColor:(UIColor*)color;

#endif
```

While if I invert the definitions it works ...
Here an example of the code that produces these errors:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
-(void)createColor:(UIColor*)color;

#elif TARGET_OS_MAC
-(void)createColor:(NSColor*)color;

#endif
```

Comment: answered that you need a static lib for IOS -- the rest of your question I don't get

Comment: I can't understand the down vote. 
Anyway I don't want to create a dynamic library... If I told you that I want to create an Helper Class multi platform does it sounds better?

Comment: because the question is really unclear to me and your comment doesnt help :D the title is "creating a non-static library" while you say "I dont want a dynamic lib" :D

Comment: you only want to embed a CLASS (a .m & .h) file in your projects?

Comment: What do you even mean by "open"? There is a static library (`.a`), a dynamic library (`.dylib`, `.so`) and a framework (`.framework`).

Comment: No I want just create .h .m files that contain functions for iOS and functions for OSX. (I'll edit the question, you are right it's not clear at all)

Comment: Have you thought about using CGColor, instead? If you're just writing similar methods, it might be easier to just write and maintain separate files for each target.

Comment: @MatterGoal I removed my down vote. Thanks! Then The defines should help you!

Comment: I do it often. it is useful for model classes.

Comment: @PaulArmstrong no help ^^ That was just an example anyways!

Comment: @PaulArmstrong yes, as Daij-Djan says it was just an example.

Comment: @MatterGoal: If the second inverted code indeed works, can you clarify and remove the trailing `"Here an example of the code that produces these errors:"` from that line?

Comment: @PaulArmstrong Or have a cross-platform base class that uses CGColor and add UIColor/NSColor support in a subclass or category.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problems you're seeing arise from the fact that `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` is defined as a variant of `TARGET_OS_MAC`. (In other words, `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` is a more-specific case of `TARGET_OS_MAC`. Or `TARGET_OS_MAC` is to a rectangle as `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` is to a square).

So the following code errors out when compiling for iOS because iOS would match both of those conditions, but `NSColor` is not defined for iOS.

```
#if TARGET_OS_MAC
-(void)createColor:(NSColor*)color;    

#elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE
-(void)createColor:(UIColor*)color;

#endif
```

The following code works properly for both because for iOS, it matches the first case, and for Mac OS X, it doesn't match the first but does match the second.

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
-(void)createColor:(UIColor*)color;

#elif TARGET_OS_MAC
-(void)createColor:(NSColor*)color;

#endif
```

Answer (score 5):

When it comes to UIColor/NSColor, I handle it like this:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#define ImageClassName UIImage
#else
#define ImageClassName NSImage
#endif
```

Then, in header files, and if you're just passing instances around, you can just use e.g. `ImageClassName *`.

Repeat the `#if` block in your code when you need to use the UIColor/NSColor APIs.

Answer (score 4):

the two defines you talk about are set to 1 or 0 depending on what you compile for! (at compilation time)

so you are on the right track here I guess

e.g.

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>
#elif TARGET_OS_MAC
#import <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
#endif
```