# How to automatically choose between NSColor and UIColor for the correct build system? (Using a #define, or something)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, c-preprocessor, uicolor, nscolor

I'm trying to make a `NSObject` subclass that will have a lot of methods that return colors, so I wanna return `UIColor` if I'm building for iOS or `NSColor` if I'm building for OS X.
This is kind of a pseudo-code of what the expected behaviour should be:

```
#define COLOR #if TARGET_OS_IPHONE UIColor #elif TARGET_OS_MAC NSColor #endif

+ (COLOR *)makeMeColorful;
```

Is it possible to do something like this instead of making 2 methods for each of my object's method (one for iOS and another for OS X)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323109/creating-an-ios-os-x-cross-platform-class?rq=1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is absolutely doable. SKColor from SpriteKit for example, is defined like:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#define SKColor UIColor
#else
#define SKColor NSColor
#endif
```

And then utilized like this:

```
SKColor *color = [SKColor colorWithHue:0.5 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0];
```

This simply takes advantage of the fact that `UIColor` and `NSColor` share some of their class methods.

Comment: Very clever Apple. ;)

Comment: Note that `NSColor` and `UIColor` don't share *all* their API, though, so you have to be careful not to call methods that exist only on one or the other.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Swift try something in the lines of

```
#if os(macOS)
    typealias Color = NSColor
#else
    typealias Color = UIColor
#endif
```

Works for macOS, iOS, tvOS and watchOS. More on [Swift's preprocessor directives](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID31).

Comment: Swift doesn't use flags like `TARGET_OS_IPHONE`. But it does have [target-platform conditionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID31) like `#if os(iOS)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `typedef` within the preprocessor conditional:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
typedef UIColor MONPlatformColor;
#elif
typedef NSColor MONPlatformColor;
#endif
```

And your API would be declared:

```
+ (MONPlatformColor *)makeMeColorful;
```