# Add /usr/include as include path for ios app

Tags: ios, macos

I found an interesting problem when I build an ios app for the simulator ios 7.1

If I add /usr/include as header search path, it tells me **CoreFoundation/CFUserNotification.h** in **CoreFoundation.h** is not found. However, as we can see from **CoreFoundation.h** :

```
#if (TARGET_OS_MAC && !(TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE))
#include <CoreFoundation/CFUserNotification.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CFXMLNode.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CFXMLParser.h>
#endif
```

Only if the target is Mac OS, we include this file, which means the build target became Mac OS?

If I remove this include path, there is no such problem, then I can run this ios app in simulator. why?

---

Update: I notice that the "system default header search path" for the ios app is /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include, so we do not need to use the /usr/include path, but the fact that using /usr/include as header search path makes it unable to compile stills confuses me.

Comment: Your question is confusing; you imply the compile fails and yet say you can still run the app.

Comment: @trojanfoe I mean if I remove this include path, then I can compile and run.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you run it in simulator ios 7.1, the compiler will search /usr/include in simulator ios 7.1, however, it doesn't exist, while your target is Mac OS, the compiler donn't complain.

Comment: You say "run" and "compiler" in the same sentence.  What do you mean?

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, but can you explain a bit more? I do not very get it...

Answer (score 0):

believe it or not `TARGET_OS_MAC` is 1 for *both* Mac and iOS.

see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323109/creating-an-ios-os-x-cross-platform-class) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

For me this happened when i added the CFLAGS and C++FLAGS on my target instead of my project.  Once i put them on the project and removed them from the target the problem went away.